# Не удаётся получить токен авторизации (VK API)

Tags: vkontakte-api, авторизация, httpclient, token

Учусь работать с VK API. Использую HttpClient (Apache). Столкнулся с трудностью авторизации — не могу программно получить токен.

Зарегистрировал Standalone-приложение, сформировал запрос для сервера:

```
String url = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=IDHERE&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends,groups,offline&response_type=token&v=5.44";
```

При использовании запросов `GET`/`POST`, в ответе получаю код страницы со скриптами.
Если ввожу в окно браузера эту же строку руками, получаю переход на указанную в запросе страницу, и в URL имею токен, который мне так необходим, вида:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=tokenHere1&expires_in=0&user_id=idHere
```

Код отправляющий GET-запрос:

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to Url : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
```

Пробовал и GET-, и POST- запросы, отлавливал сookie — безрезультатно.
Подскажите, как можно вытащить токен из ответа сервера, или из URL браузера?

Comment: Опишите процесс. Пользователь запускает приложение и должен суметь залогиниться в ВК и дать разрешение приложению? Или у вас есть пары "логин-пароль" и вы хотите полностью автоматически получить токен приложения? Как-то ещё?

Comment: Пара Логин-Пароль имеется, задача полностью программно получить токен.

Answer (score 2):

При [авторизации](https://vk.com/dev/oauth_dialog) *Standalone* приложения ВКонтакте происходит переадресация на адрес "oauth.vk.com/blank.html" и токен содержится в адресной строке. Вытащить его оттуда программно можно **только** в веб-компоненте, над которым у вас есть контроль – напр. в приложении [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). Стандартными средствами это невозможно в силу политики безопасности браузеров – документ находится в домене vk, и любым вашим скриптам к нему нет доступа.

Если вы всё же хотите попробовать полностью программно авторизовываться в ВК и давать разрешение приложению, можно попробовать использовать да хоть `curl` и правильно обрабатывать полученный HTML. Уменьшить число скриптов может помочь параметр `&display=mobile` в первоначальной ссылке на авторизацию.

Answer (score 0):

Решение есть. Apache httpCient - не позволяет выполнить операции авторизации ВКонтакте, как обычный браузер.

Но проблема решается через Selenium Web Driver - headless browser на базе PhantomJS.  Все операции проделываете как в обычном браузере, но через javascript с обращением к html-элементами. После переадресации извлекаете из  URL ответа свой токен.